# I am attempting to display json response in a div without using PHP

Tags: json, ajax

I am able to see the results of the api call with developer tools, however, I lack the knowledge that will allow me to display the results in html without php.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" rel="jquery" >    </script>
<meta name="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
</head>

<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">

<div id="fullscreen">
<div id="output">

</div>

</div>

</body>
<script>
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: "https://avacmd25.scala.com:44335/ContentManager/api/rest/players?limit=1&offset=0&sort=name",
dataType: "json",

success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response ); // server response
        var id = response[0];       
        var vname = response[1];
        $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname);
}
});
</script>
</html>
```

If it helps, here is a small sample of the response...

objectcount: 36list: Array[1]0: Objectactive: "HEARTBEAT_OVERDUE"distributionServer: ObjectdownloadThreads: 1enabled: trueid: 31lastModified: "2016-12-20 18:26:27"logLevel: "normal"mac: "00-00-00-00-00-

Answer (score 0):

I can't post comments yet, so I'll ask here. Are you sending an array as your response? And if so, are you using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on that array? If you aren't encoding it, that might explain the response you are getting.

Comment: I believe the response is coming back as an array yes... Is json encode possible without php?